# Fetch the JSON array from firebase realtime database. Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the whole JSON array from my Firebase real-time database. Fetch the Array from real-time database and store it in the `ArrayList` of custom class.

[image: Database picture is here]

Comment: I want to get the Location array

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (an example with a map)

```
    Map<String, Place> placeMap;
    DatabaseReference places;
    ArrayList<Place> placeData;
```

In onCreate

```
     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     places = database.getReference("Place");
     placeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Create method (get data in firebase)

```
    private void getAllMarkerPlace() {

            places.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        placeData = new ArrayList<>();
                        place = postSnapshot.getValue(Place.class);
                        placeMarker = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(place.getLat()), Double.valueOf(place.getLng()));
                        place.setLatLng(placeMarker);
                        placeData.add(place);
                        placeMap.put(place.getName(), place);


                        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MapsActivity.this);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(placeMarker)
                                .title(place.getName()));
                        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this);


                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }


            });

        }
```

Comment: Will it fetch the whole JSON array of location?

Comment: Yes  (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren)  - dataSnapshot.getChildren - one element(database);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `location` node is not an `array` is an object which in term holds other location objects. Second, as I see in your screenshot, your database is not so well structured. Your `collion` node should hold object of the same type. In your case, it holds user object an the `location` object. As I see, in your location object, you are actually the coordinates for your users and for that I recommend you to change the database structure as:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- collion
          |
          --- userId
                |
                --- email: "jawadkhant557@gmail.com"
                |
                --- id: "CQuL...ihq1"
                |
                --- name: "jawadkhan"
                |
                --- location
                      |
                      --- latitude: 31.54614619
                      |
                      --- longitude: 74.40240774
```

In this case, when you want to get the latitude and longitude of an user, just simply use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("collion").child(uid).child("location");
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Assuming that you have for your users, a model class named `Collion` that has three fields `email`, `id`, `name` and the `location` map plus the corresponding getters, if you want to get all user objects please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference collionRef = rootRef.child("collion");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Collion collion = ds.getValue(Collion.class);
            Log.d("TAG", collion.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
collionRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: There are no arrays in mine nor in your structure but if you want to get all user location, you can get them from the `collion` object using this line of code: `double latitude = collion.getLocation().get("latitude");` because `latitude` is a map, right?